# Function return nothing

Tags: javascript

I build this function but it return nothing :

```
function myFunction(index){
    var resultat = "";
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/File.xml', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            resultat = result['level1']['level2']['level3'][index];
            //console.log(resultat); // works
        });
    });
    return resultat;// Return nothing
    // return 'test' // Works
}
```

Hope you will can help me !

Comment: The `fs.readFile()` operation is *asynchronous*. The result won't be available until the operation finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns before your xml call has time to load the remote XML.

Try:

```
function getItem(index, callback){
    var resultat = "";
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/SearchRequest.xml', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            resultat = result['rss']['channel']['item'][index];
            //console.log(resultat); // works
            callback(resultat);
        });
    });
}

var index = 1;
getItem(index, function(d){
  console.log(d);
});
```